# JS string: Replace with index in regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have little to no experience with regex, and I was wondering how you would go about to replace a section in a string identified by regex, where the index is part of the identified section?

Here is my example string:

```
let exampleStr = "How do I {0} the {n} with the {1} in my array?";
```

This is my data array:

```
let arr = ["replace", "items"];
```

Now, with replace and regex, I would like to match the index in the {#} section with the array element matching the index.

Resulting string:

```
let result = "How do I replace the {n} with the items in my array?";
```

Notice how it would ignore the {n}, as it does not contain a numeric value.

I can do this with Array.indexOf, Number.isNaN, typeof etc, but regex seems to be the "right" and cleaner way to do it, while a bit harder to read :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need ajax for that if you know the exact strings you want to replace?

Comment: As a programmer, I really like a generic solution. But generic examples are some times hard to grasp, and might confuse the reader. So, while I'm looking for a generic solution, I find it more appropriate to give an example in a more specific manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`replace` with a callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters):

```js
let exampleStr = "How do I {0} the {n} with the {1} in my array?";
let arr = ["replace", "items"];

let result = exampleStr.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, (g0, g1)=>arr[parseInt(g1,10)]);
console.log(result);
```

The pattern is simple - it matches a number inside curly braces, and captures the number to group number 1.
The callback function parses the number (which is not strictly required, but `arr["1"]` is not pretty), and then return the proper element from the array.
The callback could use some more error checking.

Comment: @torazaburo -  You are right, but that's a style choice. `{` and `}` are metacharacters, and I usually like to escape them. This is even more justifiable here, in the context of numbers. `{\d+}` might become `{2}`, for example in a test or modified code, resulting in a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks. This solution seems to require that you know in advance that there are two strings to be replaced (`{0}` and `{1}`). What if the number of strings to be replaced is unknown, meaning there could be `{2}`, `{3}`, `{4}`, ...?

Comment: @IanY. - this should work for any number as long as you supply the right `arr` - which could be create dynamically. The first two lines here are copied from the question so I'll have runnable code.